# Red Hat Linux + Rails + RVM: Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rubygems

So I'm trying to deploy my Rails 3 app to a Red Hat Linux server that uses RVM, but it keeps failing:

```
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] 
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] checking for vm_core.h... no
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] checking for vm_core.h... no
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] Makefile creation failed
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] **************************************************************************
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] No source for ruby-1.9.3-p448 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] **************************************************************************
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] *** extconf.rb failed ***
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] details.  You may need configuration options.
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] 
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] Provided configuration options:
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] --with-opt-dir
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] --without-opt-dir
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] --with-opt-include
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] --with-opt-lib
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] --with-make-prog
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] --without-make-prog
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] --srcdir=.
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] --curdir
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] --with-ruby-dir
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] --without-ruby-dir
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] --with-ruby-include
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] --with-ruby-lib
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] 
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] 
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/www/sherry-authorize-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/debugger-linecache-1.1.2 for inspection.
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] Results logged to /usr/local/www/sherry-authorize-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/debugger-linecache-1.1.2/ext/trace_nums/gem_make.out
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] An error occurred while installing debugger-linecache (1.1.2), and Bundler
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] cannot continue.
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] Make sure that `gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2'` succeeds before
    ** [out :: myserver.server.com] bundling.
```

So I listened to the directions and made sure the gem could install on that server by SSHing to the server and running `gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2'`, and even going to the server and manually cloning the git repo and running a `bundle install` so that all the gems exist on that server. However, even with all the gems there, whenever I deploy I still get this same message. I log in as any user and type `gem list` and all the gems show up. The gems also look like they are global and in the right place:

```
[emai@511863-web3 ~]$ which gem
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/gem
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: And what was the output of `gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2'` ? And how do you deploy ?

Comment: I deploy using capistrano. Actually, `gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2'` as my user throws a `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)`, and if I try to do it as root it says gem command not found

Comment: Then that's your problem. Have you the capistrano rvm lib ?

Comment: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano

Answer (score 0):

So I just listened to Geoffroy and installed the rvm-capistrano gem, and added these lines to my capistrano script

```
set :bundle_dir, ''
set :bundle_flags, '--system --quiet'
set :rvm_type, :system
```

and it worked!

Comment: good that you find out about this :) I saw this gem when searching for cap / rbenv so I wasn't able to answer correclty !